# Running Django-selenium project on server

Tags: python, django, selenium, web-applications, server

I developed a django project in a virtual environment which uses selenium module in one of my .py programs as follows:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    self.base_url = "%s"%(website)
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
         driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign In").click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        driver.find_element_by_id("authentication_email").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("authentication_email").send_keys("%s"%(username))
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.isReturning.isTransitionToSecondary").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("authentication_password").clear()
```

It was and is running fine inside my virtual env, but when i am trying to use the same after deploying on server I'm getting the following error:

```
 WebDriverException

Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

I came to know that selenium webdriver only runs on client and not server(correct me if I'm wrong), so is there any way I can execute the same command on server? maybe importing any new modules or calling an api? Please if someone has an insight, guide me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `selenium` code should start browser session... physically. I guess your server have no such features. You may need `pyvirtualdisplay` package for this purpose, but I'm not sure that I've understood issue correctly

Comment: yeah.. selenium is unable to start the firefox session

Comment: so, obviously, you need virtual display or you'd better use `python requests` instead of `selenium`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server has no display. 
Try to take a look at virtual displays (xvnc/xvfb). 
Also you can try to use PyVirtualDisplay: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay
It could be looking like this:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
self.display.start()
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: i install pyvirtualdisplay and added the code you gave, it's giving an error like:    ▶ Local vars
/home/intern-2/newproject/newenv/Sellerworx/sellerworxapp/test.py in setUp                                                                                       self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))

    ...

▶ Local vars
/home/intern-2/newproject/newenv/Sellerworx/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py in __init__

                            self.binary, timeout),

Comment: Please make sure that you have installed any of backends: Xvfb, Xephyr, Xvnc. If not, you have to pick one of them. For example, `sudo apt-get install xvfb`.

Comment: yeah, i have already installed xvfb.. I did do a bit of research but ended up with no advancement.

Comment: @SoumiBasu could you please type `echo $DISPLAY` it your termial? What will you get?

Comment: Also, what do you have in your FirefoxBinary log_file?

Comment: can i make selenium running on server automatically open a browser on the client accessing it with "webdriver.firefox()? If not,  there supposed to be any security issue?

Comment: @SoumiBasu which client do you mean?

Comment: other pcs connected to the same network. also if webdriver is doing the problem is there a way i can open a browser with java script and call my self.driver as the window opened by the javascript? you can see my project on http://ec2-54-210-81-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com/select , i have shared the code which is calling selenium

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me, to make it work & made the selenium more faster.

```
    from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
    from selenium import webdriver

    display=Display(visible=0, size=(1325, 744))
    display.start()

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--v=99')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--multiple-process')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
    chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36')

    driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```